# How to run a Python 3.4 file on XAMPP or AMPPS

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am NOT using django framework. Just want to run a .py from webserver. Currently, I am using XAMPP and AMPPS. How to run Python 3.4 file on XAMPP or AMPPS?

mod_python does support python 3.4.
Not sure whether mod_wsgi.so supports python 3.4. If yes, where can I download it?